# Temperature threshold CrystalDiskInfo value

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure

Could you please help me get understand what this value (C2 Temperature Threshold 70) means and do I have to worry about ssd or do i need to replace? :

[image]

Comment: [Attribute 194 is temperature](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/ssds-and-smart-data).   The drive operates between 0 °C to 70 °C.  Are you particularly concerned about the temperature of your SSD?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound Thanks for response but i have another question not about 194 attribute. please see the question details and picture.

Comment: You asked bout the **C2** attribute which is **194** decimal.  Your question is less clear after your last edit.  I linked you to a description of that S.M.A.R.T attribute.  **The current temperature appears to be the last 2 characters in the raw value.**

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks a lot.. now I understood but what about temperature above which shows 39 degree Celsius in blue button  AND Health status shows good ?
Do I need to to replace my SSD ?  as this 194 attribute which is C2 is always 70 threshold

Comment: Yes; The threshold will always be 70; 34 is 27 in hex.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please help me get understand what this value (C2 Temperature Threshold 70) means:

It means that if the temperature of the SSD reaches 70°C the count would decrease.  The current temperature are last 2 characters in the raw value.

The count hasn’t decreased for your SSD

Source: [CT240BX](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/ssds-and-smart-data)